# Celery, Where does celery retrieve list of tasks schedule?

Tags: django, celery

I want to define two separate list of celery tasks for our django app.

One list of tasks should run for our webserver.
One list of tasks is run for analytics purposes.  (so it can be offline and can be run separately from webserver)

---

I have a django app and it runs tasks fine.

I want to define some more celery tasks which are not run (by our web server).
These tasks are purely analytics related and I want to run these tasks in dev servers.
So I created another `Celery app` that has these analytics-related tasks defined only.

I want to run `celery worker --app=analytics` to run these newly-defined periodic tasks, but don't want to run all the tasks I defined previously(for our web service)

When I run `celery worker --app=analytics`, it keeps finding the tasks which were previously registered for the web service.

So I removed all the imports I could find to remove the celery tasks (mainly `proj/proj/__init__.py` file where it imports `celery`)

However it keeps finding the old tasks only.. (not the full list but partial list of previously defined tasks..) ?

Where does celery get the list of registered tasks?
How can I make sure to tell my new celery to include only newly-defined tasks (in a separate file)?

I tried to change `BROKER_URL` and `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` hoping maybe something is stored there, but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: You might be calling `app.autodiscover_tasks`. Celery automatically discovers tasks from `tasks.py` modules from all the packages if this function is called.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar yeah that's a good call, but I commented out the import of the celery.py file which has that line of code..